# Windows: Batch Recurse Directories for Media File Durations Using FFmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch, ffprobe, media-info

I have various kinds of media files (e.g., .wav, .mp4) in various folders. I would like to use a batch file to produce a listing of their durations, like this:

```
D:\Some Folder 1\Movie File.mp4 | 2:15:23
E:\Some Folder 2\Audio File.mp3 | 0:08:17
```

I would manually re-run the batch file on separate drives if necessary. The listing would ideally include something like the | symbol, which I know would not be part of the Windows filename, so as to facilitate separation of file path and name from duration when parsing the list in Excel.

I have a MediaInfo command that provides a listing of specified filetypes within a single folder, like this:

```
mediainfo --output=General;%FileName%.%FileExtension%^|%Duration/String3%\r\n *.mp3 *.wav
```

My problems with that are (1) the set of possible filetypes in a folder is open-ended; I can't be confident that .mp3 and .wav (in that example) will capture them all; (2) I am not finding detailed MediaInfo documentation, so as to meet this current need and to be confident of being able to modify the command for future needs (see e.g., [Kalishian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231998/mediainfo-cli-command-line-interface-syntax-teaching-me-once-for-all)); (3) I am not a batch recursion wizard -- that is, despite trying multiple methods of of wrapping that command in a for loop, as described in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495133/batch-file-searching-for-multiple-file-formats-in-for-loop) StackExchange discussions as well as [an old Doom9 forum](https://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-139739.html) recommending `usebackq`, I am not getting it to work across multiple folders; and (4) I would ideally learn how to do this in ffmpeg/ffprobe anyway, as part of a longer-term effort to learn those tools.

In ffprobe, I found that this worked for single files:

```
ffprobe -i "input.mp4" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal
```

as an alternative to a less elegant but perhaps more adaptable [batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20555174/711879) -- though it was not clear how to get filename and duration on the same line of output. But, as with MediaInfo, I have not been able to broaden this to multiple files (e.g., replacing "input.mp4" with "*.*") or to make it recursive, using the methods cited above. For instance, I tried this adaptation of [Jack Allan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25381530/711879):

```
for /R %f in (*.*) do ffprobe -i *.* -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal
```

but that didn't produce any file information.

**My question:** how can I use ffmpeg/ffprobe in a batch file to produce a list of media files, with full paths and durations, drawn recursively from multiple folders?

Answer (score 1):

Try this from a batch file:

```
for /R %%i in (*) do ffprobe -i "%%~fi" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal
```

Try this from command prompt:

```
for /R %i in (*) do ffprobe -i "%~fi" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal
```

Comment: Fast reply. Thanks! I tried from the command prompt. It looks promising. How can I capture the output to a file? Appending " > outputlist.txt" didn't work.

Comment: To capture the output use `for /R %f in (*) do (ffprobe -i "%~ff" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal >>"filename.txt")`

Comment: That produces durations but not the accompanying filenames. I can see them scrolling in the command window; it's a question of how to capture them to a file.

Comment: Then try this: `for /R %f in (*) do (for /f %e in ('ffprobe -i "%~ff" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal') do (echo "%~ff %~e" >>filename.txt))`

Comment: Same result: lots of data onscreen, but nothing making it to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Same need here
I was very interested by an answer since I was struggling and after some tries, here is an inelegant solution but it worked for me

for /R %f in (*) do (echo "%~ff" >>"filename.txt" & ffprobe -i "%~ff" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal >>"filename.txt")